# Apply weighting to vector

Tags: matlab, vector

Is there a function for me to apply a special weight to a vector?

For example, I have my vector

```
ele = [39.7929
27.4026
64.5358
23.2248
72.0358
34.8495
16.6268
30.0106
43.4299
24.3524
10.4841
46.3654
32.7090
81.0692
27.8029
31.7253
33.6655
21.5825
70.4128
54.0883
53.0550
];
```

From this I would like to calculate a second vector, but with the condition that if the value of the ele vector:

```
ele <= 0, then a value of the 2nd vector = 10.
0 < ele <= 60, then a value of the 2nd vector = 1/(1.103*sind(ele+5°))
ele > 60, then a value of the 2nd vector = 1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using a vectorized approach:

```
ele2 = ele;
ele2(ele <= 0) = 10;
ele2(ele > 0 & ele <= 60) = 1 ./ 1.103 .* sind(ele(ele > 0 & ele <= 60) + 5);
ele2(ele > 60) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner:

```
out = 10.*(ele <= 0) + (ele > 60) + 1./(1.103.*sind(ele+5)).*((ele > 0) & (ele <= 60));
```